# Can I ask for help identifying something I've had?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask help identifying a specific type of tea. It has a single, objective answer, but it seems like it may not be appropriate for this site.

To be more specific, there are different kinds of oolong, and I want to know what type Twingings sells.

Would this question be downvoted into oblivion, or is it safe to ask?

Answer (score 4):

Asking it is fine, we do identification questions. There is usually need for enough background information so we have a chance to guess what it is, but I think that the brand name is sufficiently clear. Specialists would hopefully have had this tea and will have extra information for you.

I don't know if your quesiton is *answerable*, at least in the way that you imagine it - even if there is a subtype of oolong teas to which Twinnings' belongs, there is no need for all of them to have the same taste, maybe theirs is the only one that tastes like this. But even if this is correct, it is no barrier to asking it. I hope that people who know more about tea will give you a good answer.